# Get only common objects from a list of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have a couple arrays in my javascript code (i'm using knockout js too) and i want to get a single array that contains only the common objects of all the arrays.

My code is something like this:

```
Array1 = [{a: 1, b: 'something'}, {a: 2, b: 'something1'},{a: 3, b: 'something3'}];

Array2 = [{a: 3, b: 'something3'}, {a: 1, b: 'something'}, {a: 4, b: 'something4'}]

Array2 = [{a: 3, b: 'something3'}, {a: 1, b: 'something'}, {a: 5, b: 'something5'}]
```

So, from this arrays i want the common of all into one single array, so the result would be like this:

```
Array4 = [{a: 1, b: 'something'}, {a: 3, b: 'something3'}]
```

I have to mention that the Array1, Array2 and Array3 are inside another array like this:

```
Array0 = [Array1, Array2, Array3];
```

I hope you can help me with this, thank you!

Comment: You say "common of all", but then you include something3 in the result while is only in 2 of the arrays. Is this a typo or do you want to add something if it is in 2 of the arrays?

Comment: Take a look at [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) A reduce function in JS should do the work if you try hard, but underscore will make it easier.

Comment: Oh.. im sorry, thats an error.. im correcting now, thank you for that!

Comment: Are you interested in doing a deep compare of the objects? Is `{a:1, b: "something"}` the *same referenced object* each time, or *separate objects* with the same properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript) (but this isn't a jQuery solution -- I don't know if jQuery could make this job any easier than in POJS)

Comment: The comparation could be only by the 'a' property of the object.

Comment: I dont want to get the resulting array with duplicates :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
Array1 = [{a: 1, b: 'something'}, {a: 2, b: 'something1'},{a: 3, b: 'something3'}];
Array2 = [{a: 3, b: 'something3'}, {a: 1, b: 'something'}, {a: 4, b: 'something4'}]
Array3 = [{a: 3, b: 'something3'}, {a: 1, b: 'something'}, {a: 5, b: 'something5'}]

all = [Array1, Array2, Array3]

objects = {}
counter = {}

all.map(function(ary, n) {
    ary.map(function(obj) {
        var key = JSON.stringify(obj);
        objects[key] = obj;
        counter[key] = (counter[key] || 0) | (1 << n);
    })
})

intersection = []
Object.keys(counter).map(function(key) {
    if(counter[key] == (1 << all.length) - 1)
        intersection.push(objects[key]);
})

console.log(intersection)
```

The idea is to put all objects in a hash table using their JSON representations as keys.

Comment: be careful not to run that on too big collections of data.

Comment: @naugtur: why? the performance is linear as far as I can tell.

Comment: I guess I got worried by generating large strings from objects and then using them as keys in multiple sets. It might turn out memory-heavy, but I didn't test it - my bad. Anyway, it was not about time complexity at all.

Comment: @thg435 If i have more than 30 items in my array, the `intersection` array throws one empty array.

Comment: This was great, thank you so much! I was looking all around for a simple solution, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to write some custom code to do object comparison in javascript (something like [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)) and then use an array intersecting algorithm (like one of the posters before mentioned) to find the common elements.